# Need explaination for tag description on servers

Tags: terminology, starbound

While browsing around for servers I faced the server list featuring tags. Some are easy to understand like "pvp".
Some other like "anarchy", "dedicated" or "vanilla" means nothing to me.
Can anybody explain me their meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that Anarchy means there are no rules - feel free to destroy people's creations, loot their stuff, and kill at will.  Obviously PvP means it's a PvP server and don't go there unless you are ok dying a ton and killing other players.

I've not seen Dedicated, but Vanilla just means that it's the core game with nothing special added.  No addons, custom modes, custom settings, etc.

Comment: Dedicated probably means that it is just hosted on a dedicated server, instead of self hosting.